# Resending OTP through an API request in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to resend the otp through the email source.

This is the response I get

[image: response]

This is the docs of the api for this request

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
  function resendOtp() {

    const data = {
      email: email,
      mobile: mobile,
      source: email,
    }
    axios
    .get(`${API_URL}` + `/user/otpResend`, data)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

Should I be sending a payload for this to work? how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

These are queryParams

Try hitting the url with query Params

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams({
    ...data
}).toString();

.get(`${API_URL}` + `/user/otpResend` + params)
```

Comment: I get this error "Cannot GET /api/user/otpResendemail=yousrayk19%40gmail.com&mobile=1324567891&source=yousrayk19%40gmail.com"

Comment: yeah, because the route doesn't exist, can you do

.get(`${API_URL}` + `/user/otpResend?` + params)